# Discord.js v13 Invite tracker

Tags: discord.js

Finally getting around to updating my bot from v12 to v13 and having an issue that I can't seem to solve. I have an invite tracker that works perfectly on v12 but will not function on v13. I have included the code below, the commented lines are the v12 code that I know needed changing for v13.

```js
// const Discord = require('discord.js')
const {
    Client,
    Intents
} = require('discord.js')

// const client = new Discord.Client({
//     partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
// })
const client = new Client({
    intents: [Intents.FLAGS.GUILDS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MEMBERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_BANS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_EMOJIS_AND_STICKERS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INTEGRATIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_WEBHOOKS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_INVITES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_VOICE_STATES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_PRESENCES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.GUILD_MESSAGE_TYPING, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGES, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_REACTIONS, Intents.FLAGS.DIRECT_MESSAGE_TYPING],
    partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION']
})
const guildInvites = new Map()

// client.on('inviteCreate', async invite => guildInvites.set(invite.guild.id, await invite.guild.fetchInvites()))
client.on('inviteCreate', async invite => guildInvites.set(invite.guild.id, await invite.guild.invites.fetch()))

client.once('ready', () => {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        //guild.fetchInvites()
        guild.invites.fetch()
            .then(invites => guildInvites.set(guild.id, invites))
            .catch(err => {
                console.log(err)
                console.log(guildInvites)
                client.channels.cache.get('channelId').send({
                    content: `${err}`
                })
            })
    })
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const cachedInvites = guildInvites.get(member.guild.id)
    // const newInvites = await member.guild.fetchInvites()
    const newInvites = await member.guild.invites.fetch()
    guildInvites.set(member.guild.id, newInvites)
    try {
        const usedInvite = newInvites.find(inv => cachedInvites.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses)
        console.log(cachedInvites)
        console.log(newInvites)
        console.log(usedInvite)
        console.log(`The code ${usedInvite.code} was just used by ${member.user.username}.`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err)
        client.channels.cache.get('channelId').send({
            content: `${err}`
        })
    }
})
```

This is the console log result:

console.log(cachedInvites) => returns below

```js
Collection(2) [Map] {
    '11111111' => Invite {
      guild: Guild {
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: "Testing Server",
        icon: null,
        features: [Array],
        commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
        members: [GuildMemberManager],
        channels: [GuildChannelManager],
        bans: [GuildBanManager],
        roles: [RoleManager],
        presences: PresenceManager {},
        voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
        stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
        invites: [GuildInviteManager],
        deleted: false,
        available: true,
        shardId: 0,
        splash: null,
        banner: null,
        description: null,
        verificationLevel: 'LOW',
        vanityURLCode: null,
        nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
        discoverySplash: null,
        memberCount: 3,
        large: false,
        applicationId: null,
        afkTimeout: 900,
        afkChannelId: 'xxxx',
        systemChannelId: 'xxxx',
        premiumTier: 'NONE',
        premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
        explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
        mfaLevel: 'NONE',
        joinedTimestamp: 1633812225872,
        defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
        systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
        maximumMembers: 250000,
        maximumPresences: null,
        approximateMemberCount: null,
        approximatePresenceCount: null,
        vanityURLUses: null,
        rulesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        publicUpdatesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        preferredLocale: 'en-US',
        ownerId: 'xxxx',
        emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
        stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
      },
      code: '11111111',
      presenceCount: null,
      memberCount: null,
      temporary: false,
      maxAge: 604800,
      uses: 40,
      maxUses: 0,
      inviter: User {
        id: 'xxxx',
        bot: false,
        system: false,
        flags: [UserFlags],
        username: 'xxxx',
        discriminator: 'xxxx',
        avatar: 'xxxx',
        banner: undefined,
        accentColor: undefined
      },
      targetUser: null,
      targetApplication: null,
      targetType: null,
      channel: TextChannel {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        deleted: false,
        guild: [Guild],
        guildId: 'xxxx',
        parentId: 'xxxx',
        permissionOverwrites: [PermissionOverwriteManager],
        messages: [MessageManager],
        threads: [ThreadManager],
        nsfw: false,
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: 'welcome',
        rawPosition: 3,
        topic: null,
        lastMessageId: 'xxxx',
        rateLimitPerUser: 0
      },
      createdTimestamp: 1633922331801,
      _expiresTimestamp: null,
      stageInstance: null
    },
    '22222222' => Invite {
      guild: Guild {
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: "Testing Server",
        icon: null,
        features: [Array],
        commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
        members: [GuildMemberManager],
        channels: [GuildChannelManager],
        bans: [GuildBanManager],
        roles: [RoleManager],
        presences: PresenceManager {},
        voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
        stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
        invites: [GuildInviteManager],
        deleted: false,
        available: true,
        shardId: 0,
        splash: null,
        banner: null,
        description: null,
        verificationLevel: 'LOW',
        vanityURLCode: null,
        nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
        discoverySplash: null,
        memberCount: 3,
        large: false,
        applicationId: null,
        afkTimeout: 900,
        afkChannelId: 'xxxx',
        systemChannelId: 'xxxx',
        premiumTier: 'NONE',
        premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
        explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
        mfaLevel: 'NONE',
        joinedTimestamp: 1633812225872,
        defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
        systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
        maximumMembers: 250000,
        maximumPresences: null,
        approximateMemberCount: null,
        approximatePresenceCount: null,
        vanityURLUses: null,
        rulesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        publicUpdatesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        preferredLocale: 'en-US',
        ownerId: 'xxxx',
        emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
        stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
      },
      code: '22222222',
      presenceCount: null,
      memberCount: null,
      temporary: false,
      maxAge: 604800,
      uses: 21,
      maxUses: 0,
      inviter: User {
        id: 'xxxx',
        bot: false,
        system: false,
        flags: [UserFlags],
        username: 'xxxx',
        discriminator: 'xxxx',
        avatar: 'xxx',
        banner: undefined,
        accentColor: undefined
      },
      targetUser: null,
      targetApplication: null,
      targetType: null,
      channel: TextChannel {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        deleted: false,
        guild: [Guild],
        guildId: 'xxxxx',
        parentId: 'xxxx',
        permissionOverwrites: [PermissionOverwriteManager],
        messages: [MessageManager],
        threads: [ThreadManager],
        nsfw: false,
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: 'guest-chat',
        rawPosition: 48,
        topic: 'Guest Invitation Link',
        lastMessageId: null,
        rateLimitPerUser: 0
      },
      createdTimestamp: 1633969178889,
      _expiresTimestamp: null,
      stageInstance: null
    }
  }
```

console.log(newInvites) => returns below

```js
Collection(2) [Map] {
    '11111111' => Invite {
      guild: Guild {
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: "Testing Server",
        icon: null,
        features: [Array],
        commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
        members: [GuildMemberManager],
        channels: [GuildChannelManager],
        bans: [GuildBanManager],
        roles: [RoleManager],
        presences: PresenceManager {},
        voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
        stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
        invites: [GuildInviteManager],
        deleted: false,
        available: true,
        shardId: 0,
        splash: null,
        banner: null,
        description: null,
        verificationLevel: 'LOW',
        vanityURLCode: null,
        nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
        discoverySplash: null,
        memberCount: 3,
        large: false,
        applicationId: null,
        afkTimeout: 900,
        afkChannelId: 'xxxx',
        systemChannelId: 'xxxx',
        premiumTier: 'NONE',
        premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
        explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
        mfaLevel: 'NONE',
        joinedTimestamp: 1633812225872,
        defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
        systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
        maximumMembers: 250000,
        maximumPresences: null,
        approximateMemberCount: null,
        approximatePresenceCount: null,
        vanityURLUses: null,
        rulesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        publicUpdatesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        preferredLocale: 'en-US',
        ownerId: 'xxxx',
        emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
        stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
      },
      code: '11111111',
      presenceCount: null,
      memberCount: null,
      temporary: false,
      maxAge: 604800,
      uses: 40,
      maxUses: 0,
      inviter: User {
        id: 'xxxx',
        bot: false,
        system: false,
        flags: [UserFlags],
        username: 'xxxx',
        discriminator: 'xxxx',
        avatar: 'xxxx',
        banner: undefined,
        accentColor: undefined
      },
      targetUser: null,
      targetApplication: null,
      targetType: null,
      channel: TextChannel {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        deleted: false,
        guild: [Guild],
        guildId: 'xxxx',
        parentId: 'xxxx',
        permissionOverwrites: [PermissionOverwriteManager],
        messages: [MessageManager],
        threads: [ThreadManager],
        nsfw: false,
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: 'welcome',
        rawPosition: 3,
        topic: null,
        lastMessageId: 'xxxx',
        rateLimitPerUser: 0
      },
      createdTimestamp: 1633922331801,
      _expiresTimestamp: null,
      stageInstance: null
    },
    '22222222' => Invite {
      guild: Guild {
        id: '878285237082271744',
        name: "Testing Server",
        icon: null,
        features: [Array],
        commands: [GuildApplicationCommandManager],
        members: [GuildMemberManager],
        channels: [GuildChannelManager],
        bans: [GuildBanManager],
        roles: [RoleManager],
        presences: PresenceManager {},
        voiceStates: [VoiceStateManager],
        stageInstances: [StageInstanceManager],
        invites: [GuildInviteManager],
        deleted: false,
        available: true,
        shardId: 0,
        splash: null,
        banner: null,
        description: null,
        verificationLevel: 'LOW',
        vanityURLCode: null,
        nsfwLevel: 'DEFAULT',
        discoverySplash: null,
        memberCount: 3,
        large: false,
        applicationId: null,
        afkTimeout: 900,
        afkChannelId: 'xxxx',
        systemChannelId: 'xxxx',
        premiumTier: 'NONE',
        premiumSubscriptionCount: 0,
        explicitContentFilter: 'ALL_MEMBERS',
        mfaLevel: 'NONE',
        joinedTimestamp: 1633812225872,
        defaultMessageNotifications: 'ONLY_MENTIONS',
        systemChannelFlags: [SystemChannelFlags],
        maximumMembers: 250000,
        maximumPresences: null,
        approximateMemberCount: null,
        approximatePresenceCount: null,
        vanityURLUses: null,
        rulesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        publicUpdatesChannelId: 'xxxx',
        preferredLocale: 'en-US',
        ownerId: 'xxxx',
        emojis: [GuildEmojiManager],
        stickers: [GuildStickerManager]
      },
      code: '22222222',
      presenceCount: null,
      memberCount: null,
      temporary: false,
      maxAge: 604800,
      uses: 22,
      maxUses: 0,
      inviter: User {
        id: 'xxxx',
        bot: false,
        system: false,
        flags: [UserFlags],
        username: 'xxxx',
        discriminator: 'xxxx',
        avatar: 'xxxx',
        banner: undefined,
        accentColor: undefined
      },
      targetUser: null,
      targetApplication: null,
      targetType: null,
      channel: TextChannel {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        deleted: false,
        guild: [Guild],
        guildId: 'xxxx',
        parentId: 'xxxx',
        permissionOverwrites: [PermissionOverwriteManager],
        messages: [MessageManager],
        threads: [ThreadManager],
        nsfw: false,
        id: 'xxxx',
        name: 'guest-chat',
        rawPosition: 48,
        topic: 'Guest Invitation Link',
        lastMessageId: null,
        rateLimitPerUser: 0
      },
      createdTimestamp: 1633969178889,
      _expiresTimestamp: null,
      stageInstance: null
    }
  }
```

console.log(usedInvite) => returns undefined

The error message I get is obviously:

`TypeError: Cannot read property 'code' of undefined`

Comment: In the actual code 'channelId' is a number, just so I don't get that pointed out.

Comment: Can you update your question to include the relevant data (e.g. the invites' uses and codes -- don't include the actual codes, just show which ones are matching between the two collections) in each of the `cachedInvites` and `newInvites` collections?

Comment: @Cannicide that has been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue you are having most likely stems from the fact that you are saving the entire `Invites` Collection object in your `guildInvites` Map. Remember that in Javascript, when you save a single object in multiple different locations, each location still points to the same object. Basically, when you save the `invites` object or `invite.guild.invites.fetch()` to your `guildInvites` Map, it refers to the exact same object as `newInvites` will. In other words, `cachedInvites` and `newInvites` are both referring to the same object; because of this, they will contain the exact same values. Whenever an invite in `newInvites` is updated, it will automatically also update the invite in `cachedInvites`. This may be happening only now due to some changes in discord.js' code for invite management in v13.

I have not, however, looked at the discord.js source code for the new `InviteManager`, so it is possible that some other, similar issue is at play here. However, the solution in this answer works regardless.

Because the cache and new invite lists were both the same, the uses between the cached and used invite ended up being equal (causing the `cachedInvites.get(inv.code).uses < inv.uses` condition to not be met). Thus, `newInvites.find()` could not find the invite you were looking for, and `usedInvite` ended up being `undefined`.

There are several ways you could fix this issue. My preference is to not save the entire `invites` collection to your invite cache. Since you only need to know the cached invite's code and old number of uses, you only need to save that information.  No need to save entire `Invite` objects to your cache when you only need two small pieces of information from each cached invite.

This is my proposed new structure of your `cachedInvites`. As you can see, it is much simpler and more efficient than before. It also solves the aforementioned possible JS issues with a single object being saved to multiple locations, by not directly saving the `invites` object in your cache.

```js
Collection(2) [Map] {
    '11111111' => 40,
    '22222222' => 21
}
```

And here is my full solution, using this new, simpler structure for cached invites. I've tested it, and it works:

```js
client.on('inviteCreate', async invite => {
    const invites = await invite.guild.invites.fetch();

    const codeUses = new Map();
    invites.each(inv => codeUses.set(inv.code, inv.uses));

    guildInvites.set(invite.guild.id, codeUses);
})

client.once('ready', () => {
    client.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
        guild.invites.fetch()
            .then(invites => {
                console.log("INVITES CACHED");
                const codeUses = new Map();
                invites.each(inv => codeUses.set(inv.code, inv.uses));

                guildInvites.set(guild.id, codeUses);
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log("OnReady Error:", err)
            })
    })
})

client.on('guildMemberAdd', async member => {
    const cachedInvites = guildInvites.get(member.guild.id)
    const newInvites = await member.guild.invites.fetch();
    try {
        const usedInvite = newInvites.find(inv => cachedInvites.get(inv.code) < inv.uses);
        console.log("Cached", [...cachedInvites.keys()])
        console.log("New", [...newInvites.values()].map(inv => inv.code))
        console.log("Used", usedInvite)
        console.log(`The code ${usedInvite.code} was just used by ${member.user.username}.`)
    } catch (err) {
        console.log("OnGuildMemberAdd Error:", err)
    }

    newInvites.each(inv => cachedInvites.set(inv.code, inv.uses));
    guildInvites.set(member.guild.id, cachedInvites);
});
```